# Stop it including row 2

Tags: excel, vba

So i managed to find this code that seems to work well for grabbing the data, splitting it out onto separate new tabs, based on what it finds in column H. However, on all the new tabs it creates, it still brings over the original row2 - i'm sure somewhere within it, i need to just change a value, but haven't spotted where?

```
Option Explicit

'<<<<  Create a new sheet for every Unique value  >>>>>

'This example copy all rows with the same value in the first column of
'the range to a new worksheet. It will do this for every unique value.
'The sheets will be named after the Unique value.

'Note: this example use the function LastRow in the ModReset module

Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A11 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A2:S65000")
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 8

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("H1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("H2:H" & Lrow)

        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
                                                        Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet
            Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            On Error Resume Next
            WSNew.Name = cell.Value
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With WSNew.Range("A1")
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        'Show all data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Hoping its just i minor change needed.

Comment: I believe that you are copy the displayed cells of the auto filter, so the headers will be displayed

Comment: You could look at doing something like so `Set rVisible = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rmodify = rVisible.Areas(1).Resize(rVisible.Areas(1).Rows.Count - 1, 2).Offset(1, 0)` then copy `rVisible`  So here I have a new range `rModify` to hold the result, but you could do straight in the `area` it uses `resize` and `offset`...... there is probably a simper way though

Comment: So, would you like to just copy the filtered area, but without the headers?

Comment: Change `My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` to `My_Range.Offset(1).(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Comment: @GMalc: I am afraid this doesn't work in not contiguous ranges (like `(xlCellTypeVisible)`) returns. It is necessary to really count the `visibleCells` range and apply the offset after that I think... If you would try `Debut.Print My_Range.Rows.Count`, it will return only the first Area number of rows. Ranges obtained based on `xlCellTypeVisible` are tricky...

Comment: Try this. Change `My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` to this `My_Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy`

Comment: You can see an example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207)

Comment: @FaneDuru: No disrespect, but I have tested this and it works when copy/pasting to a new worksheet. After autofilter it copies the filtered data but does not copy the first row of `My_Range`. The OP does not want to copy the top row, and ask for a `minor change`. There are times when you need to count the rows for a visible area and use `Resize` and `Offset`,but i don't think it was needed for this task.

Comment: @GMalc: Not any problem with me. Your code (like you wanted to post it) works! I messed it up when "adapted" a little. You missed `SpecialCells` and I wrongly 'corrected' it... So, you are right! I also tried something similar on my own and I was surprised that it does not act as (I) expected in terms of `range.Rows.Count`. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, I didn't even notice that I missed `SpecialCells`

Comment: @GMalc: I believe you, it was obvious... **I** was not enough attentive to put it where it should obvious it was missing. So, your posted solution works! Mine, was a workaround of a type 'why simple when complicated is possible'... :)